# Summation of two normed affinely transformed vectors as an affine transformed vector and constant

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, numerical-linear-algebra

I have two affine-transformed vectors, where I take the L2-nom squared of each.

$||\mathbf{A}_1 \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}_1||^2 + ||\mathbf{A}_2 \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}_2||^2$

Assuming $\mathbf{A}_1$ and $\mathbf{A}_2$ are invertible, and the $\mathbf{A}$'s are $n\times n$, $\mathbf{x}$ is $n\times 1$, and $\mathbf{b}$'s are $n\times 1$. Can these be put in the following form:

$|| \mathbf{A}_3 \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}_3 ||^2 + k$

where $k$ is some combination of $\mathbf{A}_1,\mathbf{A}_2,\mathbf{b}_1,\mathbf{b}_2$, same with $\mathbf{A}_3$ and $\mathbf{b}_3$. What is that combination? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $A_1, A_2$ are invertible then the matrix $P=A_1^\dagger A_1+A_2^\dagger A_2$ is hermitian and positive definite and hence, also invertible. Then it possible to find a matrix $A_3$ such that $P=A_3^\dagger A_3$. Likewise, $A_3$ is also invertible.

Setting $y=A_3x$ temporarily in the sum of quadratic forms and expanding them out we obtain the expression

$$||A_1A_3^{-1}\mathbf{y} + \mathbf{b}_1||^2 + ||A_2A_3^{-1}\mathbf{y} + \mathbf{b}_2||^2=\mathbf{y}^\dagger \mathbf{y}+\mathbf{v}^\dagger \mathbf{y}+\mathbf{y}^\dagger \mathbf{v}+\mathbf{b_1}^\dagger \mathbf{b_1}+\mathbf{b_2}^\dagger \mathbf{b_2}\\=||\mathbf{y}+\mathbf{v}||^2+\mathbf{b_1}^\dagger \mathbf{b_1}+\mathbf{b_2}^\dagger \mathbf{b_2}-\mathbf{v}^\dagger \mathbf{v}$$

Here we have defined

$$\mathbf{v}=(A_1A_3^{-1})^\dagger\mathbf{ b}_1+(A_2A_3^{-1})^\dagger \mathbf{b}_2$$

Reverting back to $x$ notation, we have successfully combined the quadratic forms together.

$$||A_1\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}_1||^2 + ||A_2\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}_2||^2=||A_3\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{c}||^2+ k $$

where

$$ \mathbf{c}=(A_1A_3^{-1})^\dagger\mathbf{ b}_1+(A_2A_3^{-1})^\dagger \mathbf{b}_2~~,~ k=\mathbf{b_1}^\dagger \mathbf{b_1}+\mathbf{b_2}^\dagger \mathbf{b_2}-\mathbf{c}^\dagger \mathbf{c}$$

**Note**: One can construct $A_3$ for a diagonalizable matrix for example by considering the eigenvalue decomposition $P=Q D Q^\dagger$, in which case we can set

$$A_3=D^{1/2}Q^\dagger~~,~ A_3^{-1}=A_3^\dagger D^{-1}$$

A similar construction can be attempted for invertible matrices that are not diagonalizable, by using the Jordan decomposition.